# OpenVPN useradd error

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn

I tried to install an OpenVPN access server in Centos 6 on a linode VPS.

The installation is okay for my ubuntu 11.10 distro in another VPS. The installation error occours when adding the user "openvpn" in Centos.

The error message is

```
"useradd: canot open /etc/passwd"
```

The detail of My "/etc/passwd" file:

```
"-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1194 Oct  9 00:33 /etc/passwd"
```

I am not quite familiar with Centos, so how can I add the user "openvpn" in order to setup the VPN service?

Thanks.

Comment: Are these messages generated by the openvpn pacakge, or are you running things by hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found out solution for this.

The attributes of "/etc/passwd" and "/etc/shadow" are set hiden in Centos.

Change the attributes of the two files by the following two commands:

```
chattr -ai /etc/passwd
chattr -ai /etc/shadow
```

Then I can add user by typing:

```
useradd -s /sbin/nologin openvpn
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only adding one user account I would user `adduser` not `useradd`. Adduser has a friendlier interface. Ontop of that, make sure you can access /etc/passwd, do `cat /etc/passwd` and make sure you can actually see that file and its not user permissions.

Comment: `cat /etc/passwd` does very little to verify that you can write to the file, especially given that the permissions as stated by the OP are 644.

Comment: I am in root, and "cat /etc/passwd" is Okay, and using adduser "adduser -s /sbin/nologin "opevpn"", stiil the same error message:"adduser: cannot open /etc/passwd ".